# JMS topic subscribers do not receive messages when they aren't connected

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have one publisher which is publishing messages on topic, and I have 2 subscribers S1 & S2 which are receiving the messages. When my publisher sends a message and both subscribers are up then they both receive the message. However, when my subscribers are *not* up and my publisher sends a message then when the subscribers come up they do not receive the message. How can my subscribers receive messages sent when they are not up?

Note: I am using Spring Boot.

MessageProducer.java

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/produce")
public class MessageProducer {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageProducer.class);

    @Autowired
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/{message}")
    public void run(@PathVariable("message") final String message) throws Exception {
        final String messageText = "Hello Blockchain World";
        LOG.info("============= Sending " + message);
        sendMessage(message);
    }

    public void sendMessage(String payload) {
        this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("example", payload);
    }
}
```

application.properties - (MessageProducer)

```
spring.qpidjms.remoteURL=amqp://127.0.0.1:5672
spring.qpidjms.username=admin
spring.qpidjms.password=admin
activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
server.port=8888
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
```

`MessageConsumer.java`:

```java
@Component
public class MessageConsumer {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageConsumer.class);

    @JmsListener( destination = "example")
    public void processMsg(String message) {
        LOG.info("============= Received: " + message);
    }
}
```

MessageConsumer main Initiator class (ignore class name)

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class QpidJMSSpringBootHelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QpidJMSSpringBootHelloWorld.class, args);
    }
}
```

Second consumer is same as first one just port no has been changed in application.properties

`application.properties` (MessageConsumer-1, S1)

```
spring.qpidjms.remoteURL=amqp://127.0.0.1:5672
spring.qpidjms.username=admin
spring.qpidjms.password=admin
activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
server.port=9999
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
```

`application.properties` (S2)

```
spring.qpidjms.remoteURL=amqp://127.0.0.1:5672
spring.qpidjms.username=admin
spring.qpidjms.password=admin
activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
server.port=9990
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. You say, "Could you please explain which properties i need to set?" However, you don't explain what specifically you're trying to do.  Please clarify.

Comment: Hey Justin 
1. Basically In anycast routing suppose i run the sender first and send some messages then those will be saved in queue and when i run receiver then those will be received by it. (Here I run receiver after sending the messages, means receiver was not up when i send messages).

Comment: 2.  With multicast routing I did the same, I first run the sender then I sent some messages those messages should be saved in Topic and now when i run the receivers those msgs should be received by both receivers. But it's not happening where as when receivers are up and suppose then i am sending msgs then it's been received by both receivers

Comment: So basically what i want to do is When sender is up and receivers are not and if i send some msgs to Topic then those should be received by receivers whenever they will be up at any time in future. Sorry for confusion sir. Please let me know if you still didn't get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messages sent to a multicast address (i.e. a JMS *topic*) are routed to all existing multicast queues (i.e. JMS *subscriptions*). If no subscriptions exist then the messages are discarded. This is the fundamental semantics of multicast routing (i.e. JMS *publish-subscribe*).

If you want messages for a subscriber to be stored when the subscriber is not connected then the subscriber must create a *durable* subscription before any messages which it wants are sent. Once the durable subscription is created the messages sent to the topic will be stored in that subscription even if the subscriber is not connected.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Could please let me know how can i create durable Topics here? I am using springBoot application and i have updated the code in question sir.

Comment: Sorry we were updating at the same time. Tell me what i can update so it will be clear.